# What is wrong with my bash script that uses my java code?

Tags: bash

I am writing a simple java and bash program, but it is not working. Let me know where is wrong.

Bash:

```
    for i in [1..100]; do 
         echo $i
         java prob2 $i 
    done
```

Java:

```
import java.io.*;

public class prob2
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
            int l = args.length;
            if ( l == 1 )
            {
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                    while ( num != 0 && num != 1)
                            num = num - 2;
                    if ( num == 0 )
                            System.out.println("Even");
                    else if ( num == 1 )
                            System.out.println("Odd");
            }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[1..100]" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527) at prob2.main(prob2.java:10)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[1..100]"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
        at prob2.main(prob2.java:10)

Comment: The exception shows that bash doesnt interpret `[1..100]` as a sequence but passes it as only value in the list, try `for i in $(seq 1 10);`.

Comment: I removed the Java tag because there is no Java in this problem.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you need to look up how to use the modulo operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how you would do a bash loop. Try this:

```
for i in `seq 1 100`; do 
     echo $i
     java prob2 $i 
done
```

As an aside, a faster algorithm for determining if a number is odd or even is to take it modulo 2:

```
if (num % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.println("Even");
} else {
    System.out.println("Odd");
}
```

Comment: so my algorithm is O(n)...what is modulo?

Comment: "In computing, the modulo operation finds the remainder of division of one number by another." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 4):

You have to use curly braces, not array brackets:

```
 for i in {1..100}; do 
         echo $i
         java prob2 $i 
    done
```